# Laravel 4 oneToMany Relationship

Tags: php, laravel

Being very new to database construction, I have come across the need for relationships, however I am struggling to wrap my head around the new concept.

What I need is a series of images in a gallery, that belongs to a product for an e-comm site.

I have a Gallery Model, and a Product Model.

My Product Model:

```
class Product extends Eloquent{   

    public function galleries(){
        return $this->hasMany('Gallery');      
    }
}
```

My Gallery Model:

```
class Gallery extends Eloquent{

    public function product(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Product', 'product_id');           
    }
}
```

Within my Controller:

```
public function getView($id){
    return View::make('store/view')->with('product', Product::find($id))->with('gallery', Gallery::all());
}
```

Within my View:

```
@foreach($gallery as $galPic)
        {{$galPic->product->title}}

@endforeach
```

As a result, I get a none object error.

Any advice is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: do all of your gallery records have a valid value for product_id?

Comment: so 1 product can have multiple galleries, and each gallery can have multiple photos?

Comment: TonyArra you nailed it.. In my gallery table, the product_id column contained 1 or 2s... whereas in  my product table the id column began at 6. This was due to me learning about inserting values and forgot about  the AI! 
Thanks very much I was sure my lack of knowledge would have caused mistakes in the code, and completely overlooked the DB.

Comment: @Benji40 no problem! Be sure to use proper foreign keys via the migration to prevent this. (would also suggest eager loading)

Comment: Yes a huge oversight on my part. I have never heard of eager loading but I will be sure to look it up, thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this in your controller. It should work.

```
public function getView($id){
    return View::make('store.view')->with('product', Product::find($id));
}
```

And in your View:

```
@foreach($product->galleries as $galPic)
        //then use $galPic To show ralated pics of the product
@endforeach
```